# Is there a way to tell if a classpath resource is a file or a directory?

Tags: java, classpath

For example, this snippet throws a NullPointerException(!) on the `stream.read()` line, assuming the com.google package exists in a JAR somewhere (Guava, for example).

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("com/google");
InputStream stream = resource.openStream();
System.out.println(stream.toString()); // Fine -- stream is not null
stream.read(); // NPE inside FilterInputStream.read()!
```

If `com/google` is swapped with a package that's in the file system rather than a JAR, then the snippet doesn't crash at all.  In fact, it seems to read the files in that directory, separated by newlines, though I can't imagine that behaviour is specified anywhere.

Is there a way test if the resource path "com/google" points to a "normal" resource file or to a directory?

Comment: `try { stream.read(); System.out.println("It's on the filesystem!"); } catch (NullPointerException npe) { System.out.println("It's in a JAR!"); }`

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu I want to distinguish between classpath directories and files, not "files in a JAR" and "files or directories on the file system".  Also I'd prefer not to rely on anything that undocumented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bit of a mess due to some unspecified behaviour for the protocol handlers involved in loading these resources. In this particular situation, there are two: `sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler` and `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler`, and they each handle the directory case a bit differently. Based on some experiments, here's what they each do:

**sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler**:

- What this `Handler` does is open a [`FileURLConnection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/file/FileURLConnection.java), which does [exactly what you discovered it did](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/file/FileURLConnection.java#191) when confronted with a directory. You can check if it's a directory just with:

  ```
  if (resource.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
      return new File(resource.getPath()).isDirectory();
  }
  ```

**sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler**:

- This `Handler`, on the other hand, opens a [`JarURLConnection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection.java#JarURLConnection) which eventually [makes its way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/zip/ZipFile.java#347) to a `ZipCoder`. If you take a look at that code, you'll notice something interesting: `jzentry` will come back `null` from the native JNI call because the JAR zip file does not, in fact, contain a file called `com/google`, and so it returns null to the stream that wraps it.

However, there is a solution. Although the `ZipCoder` won't find `com/google`, it *will* find `com/google/` (this is how most ZIP interfaces work, for some reason). In that case, the `jzentry` will be found, and it'll just return a null byte.

So, cutting through all these random implementation-specific behaviours, you can probably figure out if it's a directory by first trying to access the resource with a trailing `/` ([which is what `URLClassLoader`s expect for directories anyway](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)). If `ClassLoader.getResource()` returns non-null, then it's a directory. If it doesn't, try without the trailing slash. If it returns non-null, it's a file. If it still returns null, then it's not even an existing resource.

Kinda hacky, but I don't think there's anything better. I hope this helps!

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Sadly `getResource("path/to/file.txt/")` returns non-null even if `file.txt` is a regular file.

Comment: Wow. Go Java. Okay, does this happen only for the `file` protocol, or also for the `jar` protocol? I suspect only the former.

Comment: If this only happens for `file`, as I suspect it does, then just use the `resource.getProtocol()` check above to treat that case separately, and the trailing-`/` trick should still work for `jar`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *safe* and *generic* way to detect this. When you use ClassLoader.getResource(), the ClassLoader can return practically anything in the URL, in principle even something you have never seen before if the ClassLoader implements its own URL scheme (and protocol).

Your only option is to analyze the URL returned by getResource(), the protocol should hint at what it is (e.g. "file://"). But beware, depending on environment it may return things you did not plan for.

But to just access a resource, you don't *care* where it comes from (you may care if you're debugging a configuration issue, but your code should not care).

In general you should not make assumptions about the returned InputStream's capabilities, i.e. do not rely on it supporting mark/reset etc. The only safe operation would be simply reading the Stream. If an IOException occurs during read it indicates a problem with access to the resource (network connection lost etc.).

EDIT: getResource() should IMO only return resources (e.g. files or zip file entries), but never *directories* (since they are not resources). However I wouldn't count on every possible ClassLoader to do so, and I'm not sure what the correct behavior is (if its even specified somewhere).

Comment: I figured the answer might be like this. I do treat classpath resources like this, but I'd like do something smarter than throw an NPE in a later `read()` if someone accidentally passes `com/company` instead of `com/company/resource.txt` to my API

Comment: If the URL returns you some stream with delayed error detection as your snippet suggests, I would just accept it failing on the first read. The only nitpick I have about this is that it really should throw an IOException and not an NPE. But I would certainly not break a leg to make up for an oddity in the JRE. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Sadly in this case it was garbage in, a long time spent remotely debugging a weird stack trace out.

Answer (score -3):

I think that there are 2 solutions.

1. Naive solution based on analysis of the path itself. If it ends with `.jar` or `.zip` or `.war` or `.ear` it is a file. Otherwise it is a directory. I think that this approach will work in 99.99% of cases unless somebody tries to make you you to fail on purpose. For example by defining soft link that looks like a directory but is a file or vise versa.
2. Try to mimic the JVM logic that interprets paths of classpath relatively to the current working directory. So, retrieve current working directory by using `new File(".")`, then take classpath, split it and for each its element use `new File(".", classPathElement)` unless it is defined using absolute path.

Good luck with this.

Comment: Perhaps I could make my question clearer.  I'm not talking about classpath *entries*, I'm talking about classpath *resources*, i.e., the files inside those JARs/WARs.  src/main/resources in Maven-speak, for example.

Comment: @Tavian Barnes, your question is clear. This is what I am talking about. Once you can read classpath entry you definitely can determine the type if classpath resource. If entry is file path just use regular file API to check the type of the resource. If it is a jar, use `JarInputStream`

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't get that you meant to scan the classpath and open the entries myself.  While that is reasonable I'd like to be able to handle arbitrary classpaths using the existing ClassLoader infrastructure.  Otherwise my app will break in exotic environments.

Comment: Resources are not Files.