# Spring Boot returns "200 OK" (Empty Response) for resource directory, not file

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, staticresource

I am building a basic Spring Boot app, using the built is resource handler.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/")
        .setCachePeriod(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(versionResourceResolver);
```

The file structure is as follows:

```
src
  main
    java
      ..
    resources
      public
        js
          app.js
```

Making a request to `localhost:8080/js/app.js` works as expected, returning the contents of the file with the correct MIME type.

However, making a request to the container directory also returns `200 OK` and an empty response!

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/js/
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /js/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2016 21:13:26 GMT
< X-Application-Context: application
< Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Nov 2016 21:06:28 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

How can I get this to return `404 Not Found` instead? It's not a huge issue, but definitely not what I'd expected.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to be able to see what handler is being implemented for the resource response. I couldn't find it in the source code for Spring.

Comment: use registry.addResourceHandler("/")

Comment: Can you provide sample code? I have tried to do it myself and it returns 404.

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski Will do, right after I get home from work - thanks!
Also, are you sure your assets are ClassPathResources? I think that is the issue here.

Comment: @ManuelMenzella I am sure, they're ClassPathResources

Comment: Hmm, strange. I now suspect this may only be an issue when running on Linux - I have my setup configured to launch a docker container running Ubuntu and run the server there. I'll double check when I get home.

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski Ok, verified this definitely only happens on Linux, which is kind of expected because directories are treated differently.
As a workaround, we can define a custom PathResourceResolver that returns null if the resource stream is empty.

Comment: Actually, it might be a difference between OpenJDK and Oracle's JDK.

Comment: @ManuelMenzella we cannot confirm/exclude anything without the sample code :) I have also run that on Linux and it worked

Comment: Sorry :) Here is a repository that reproduces the behaviour. It needs Docker and Gradle to be installed - simply run 'run.sh'. You can then request the "directory" by running "curl -v http://localhost:8080/js" from another tab.

https://github.com/manuelmenzella/TestBug

This happens both with OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. The only thing I can think of is that Docker does something funny to directories?

Comment: It might be undefined behaviour, from what I can gather...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105554/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-classpath-resource-is-a-file-or-a-directory
@MaciejDobrowolski

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to run in Docker. The issue occurs when running from a Jar. So "gradle build" followed by "java -jar path/to/jar/file.jar". @MaciejDobrowolski